# Passing Environmental Variables into sh in Procfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, sh, foreman, procfile

I have a Procfile containing:

```
someprocess: sh -c 'cd /Users/someuser/path/to/sinatra/app && rackup -p 4567'
```

I need to break this path out so that it is configured via an environmental variable. So I've added this path to my environmental variables stored in a .env file:

```
SOME_DIR=/Users/someuser/path/to/sinatra/app
```

and I tell foreman to load these envs when I run it:

```
$ foreman start -f Procfile.dev -e .env
```

However, this causes an error as this environmental variable is not available inside the shell command:

```
someprocess: sh -c SOME_DIR && rackup -p 4567'
```

Produces an error:

```
sh: line 0: cd: SOME_DIR: No such file or directory
```

**So how can I pass the environmental variables into the shell command?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are missing $ sign for accessing the variable

```
cd $SOME_DIR
```